# How to effectively update a record using hibernate & jparepository

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I'm trying to implement a method for updating a database record. So far, I created this one:

```
public Optional<User> update(final Integer id,final UpdateUserDto dto) {

    userRepository.findById(id).ifPresent((user -> {

        user.setShop((dto.getShopId() == null) ? null : shopRepository.findById(dto.getShopId())
                .orElseThrow(ShopNotFoundException::new));

        user.setUsername(dto.getUsername());
        user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(dto.getPassword()));
        user.setRoles(Arrays.asList(
                roleRepository.findByRoleName(dto.getRole()).orElseThrow(RoleNotFoundException::new)
        ));

    }));


    return userRepository.findById(id);
}
```

But now I added two more fields to my user entity (activated, productAllowed) and I must enhance my update method to make them updatable. I can do that, but I have other entities also and if I change them it will be a lot of maybe boilerplate code.

Is there any kind of best practice to do this in a better way, or I just need to keep setting all the fields manually?

I was also thinking about reflection, but in that case I have a few fields that cannot be copied exactly from the DTO to the entity (e.g. the shop field, which is queried from database, or role field).

And I also don't think that another query for returning the new object is effective, but although I set the properties in a service layer, the original findById()'s returned user is wrapped inside an Optional, so I don't think it will be updated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can use something like [MapStruct](http://mapstruct.org) to map the properties. Saves you writing the easy mappings. The user returned will come from the first level cache and should be updated. If that isn't the case you aren't running this code inside a single transaction.

Comment: Oh, yes. It is updated, I don't know why I was sure about that not being updated. Thanks. I'll also look at mapstruct, but seems like to me it's only effective when we have entities that contain only easy mappings. Or can I add additional manual mapping on top of the easy ones?

Comment: Would be a bit worthless if you wouldn't be able to specify manual mappings now would it. I suggest a read of the documentation.... (Hint no it isn't only effective when there are only easy mappings).

Comment: Oh yay, I found the exact thing in their examples. Nice, thank you very much. (I think if you copy your comment into an answer, I can accept it as a solution. :) )